# Extracting MAC address from ifconfig output

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ifconfig, mac-spoofing

I am writing a `#!bin/bash` shell script to automate MAC spoofing. In the script that I have written I make the outputs of `ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr` equivalent to two different variables. The command `ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr` returns

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

and

```
wlan0 Link uncap: Ethernet HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

but I want the command to return *just* the MAC address for `wlan0`.

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated, use `ip`.

Comment: The command `ifconfig` is not deprecated in MAC OS? Is the command deprecated in all Linux distributions or just a few?

Comment: @Eric: For Linux, `ifconfig` is considered deprecated, but it doesn't do you a lot of harm to use it.  It is highly unlikely to disappear any time soon.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig

Comment: @Eric: For OS X, you're right, `ifconfig` is still the preferred tool, but it is a significantly different beast than Linux's `ifconfig` and is, in fact, closer to Linux's `ip` in functionality.

Comment: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00780.html

Comment: I agree but I am shooting for cross-compatibility for all things *nix, whether it be Linux or Unix.

Comment: @Eric: I was referring to Linux.

Comment: Your question is tagged with Linux and not Mac OS.

Comment: @Cyrus `+1 Upvote` agreed, if question is tag for `linux` then why people talking about `OSX` and other flavor

Comment: I just updated the tag.

Comment: @Eric if you looking for all platform run-able script then you have to first detect `OS` and base on that run specific function or command to get `MAC`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
[root@linux ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
00:25:90:F0:3F:92
```

By specifying `wlan0` as the first argument to `ifconfig`, you are telling it you only want information about that particular interface, so you should only get a single line returned.

The `grep` command then searches for a MAC address in the output and prints only the portion of the `ifconfig` output which matches.

## OR

Just for your script you can try follwong:

```
ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr | awk '{print $5}'
```

## OSX

```
ifconfig en1 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

Comment: Do you mean `wlan0` instead of `eth0` ?

Comment: I have edited answer, you can just use `awk` to extract MAC field

Comment: Do you think that `ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr | awk '{print $5}'` is preferable over `cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`? If so, why?

Comment: @Eric there are many way to extract `MAC` address its depend on you, which one satisfying your need.

Comment: Brrrr.... `grep` and `awk` in the same pipe-snake??? It can be reduced to: `awk '/HWaddr/{print $5}'`

Comment: What's wrong with `grep` and `awk` in the same pipe-snake?

Comment: Don't forget to answer question if it's helpful